# Loading scene asynchronously in Unity3D not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, asynchronous, loading, scene

So I've done some research about how loading scenes asynchronously works on unity. So far I've found two ways of doing that are very similar and that are based in the same principle.

```
   StartCoroutiune(loadScene());

    private AsyncOperation async;

     // ...

    IEnumerator loadScene(){
          async = SceneManager.LoadAsyncScene("Scene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
            async.allowSceneActivation = false;
            while(async.progress < 0.9f){
                  progressText.text = async.progress+"";
            }
           while(!async.isDone){
                  yield return null;
            }

    }

    public void showScene(){
     async.allowSceneActivation = true;
    }
```

However this doesn't seem to work for me. I still get tons of loading time and the scene shows immediately even if I haven't called the code to show it. I have also tried doing

```
SceneManager.LoadAsyncScene("Scene", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

So here is my class in charge of doing this job. I excuse myself if I my error is too simple, I'm new with Unity. Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager_StartGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameManager_MasterMenu gameManagerRef;
    private AsyncOperation loadGame;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SetInitialReferences();
        StartCoroutine("loadMainScene");//loads scene before the game starts
        gameManagerRef.ContinueGameEvent += StartGame; //subscribing the StartGame method to an Event
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
       gameManagerRef.ContinueGameEvent -= StartGame;//getting the references to the game Manager
    }

    void SetInitialReferences()
    {
        gameManagerRef = GetComponent<GameManager_MasterMenu>();
    }

    IEnumerator loadMainScene()
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("ASYNC LOAD STARTED - " +
        "DO NOT EXIT PLAY MODE UNTIL SCENE LOADS... UNITY WILL CRASH");
        loadGame = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1,LoadSceneMode.Single);
        loadGame.allowSceneActivation = false;//setting the allowscene to false so that it won't show it immediately
        yield return loadGame;
    }


    void StartGame()
    {
        if (GameReferences.currentSave == null)
        {
            GameReferences.currentSave = GameReferences.dBConnector.GetLastSave();
        }
        loadGame.allowSceneActivation = true; //is activated from the outside
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the progress while loop, you never trigger the yield when loading.
Try put it into async while loop, like

```
IEnumerator loadScene(){
      async = SceneManager.LoadAsyncScene("Scene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
      async.allowSceneActivation = false;

      while(!async.isDone){
              progressText.text = async.progress+"";
              yield return null;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
   
SceneManager.LoadScene(1, LoadSceneMode.Single);

//SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync - (Loads the Scene asynchronously in the background.)
//1 - (BuildIndex or "my scene" StringName.)
//LoadSceneMode.Additive - (Adds the Scene to the current loaded Scenes.)
//LoadSceneMode.Single - (Closes all current loaded Scenes and loads a Scene.)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to siusiulala's answer (can't comment yet) I'd remind to test asynchronous loading in a built Player separate from Editor Play Mode. Unity's Editor Play Mode does not handle asynchronous loading cleanly and often looks like it just loads synchronously, so even after fixing the implementation you should still test in a built Player.